# Discard all result of same user if one match in result set

Tags: elasticsearch

My requirement is if user has not  performed e2 then that user will not come in result. For example here user_id 15371082 has performed e2 ,e3 but because user has performed e2 so both record of user(e2,e3) for userid  15371082 will discard from result

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "a",
"user_id": 15371080,
"event" : 'e1'

},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "a",
"user_id": 15371082,
"event" : 'e2'

},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "a",
"user_id": 15371081,
"event" : 'e3'

},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "a",
"user_id": 15371082,
"event" : 'e3'

}
```

Expected result
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "user_id": 15371080,
    "event" : 'e1'

```
},

{
"id": 1,
"name": "a",
"user_id": 15371081,
"event" : 'e3'

}
```

My result should like above

Answer (score 0):

Right way would be to create unique document for each user_id and add event as nested document.

Mapping:

```
PUT eventindex/_mappings
{
  "properties": {
    "name":{
      "type": "text"
    },
    "user_id":{
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "event":{
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "name":{
          "type":"text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

`````
[
      {
        "_index" : "eventindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "tT1IL20Bcyz1xvxninMr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "b",
          "user_id" : 2,
          "event" : [
            {
              "name" : "e1"
            },
            {
              "name" : "e3"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "eventindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "tj1ML20Bcyz1xvxngXNn",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "a",
          "user_id" : 1,
          "event" : [
            {
              "name" : "e2"
            },
            {
              "name" : "e3"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
````
Query:
````
GET eventindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
           "nested": {
             "path": "event",
             "query": {
               "term": {
                 "event.name": {
                   "value": "e2"
                 }
               }
             }
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
````

Result:
````
 [
      {
        "_index" : "eventindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "tT1IL20Bcyz1xvxninMr",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "b",
          "user_id" : 2,
          "event" : [
            {
              "name" : "e1"
            },
            {
              "name" : "e3"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
````
`````